# Breaker Box problems

Tags: electrical

My family and i just moved into a mobile home.  Only one problem, the breaker to our plugs is a 15, i was told that means 110, well we cant use all the plugs in our house at the same time or it causes the breaker to flip. What can we do to fix this situation to where we can use all the plugs in our house?

Comment: There might be maintenance issue that can be corrected. Loose connections, the breaker may be worn and need replacement.  You really haven't provided enough information for anyone to help you.  The best thing you can do is call an electrician to come evaluate the situation and provide any maintenance needed.

Comment: Are you saying they all connect to the same 15 amp breaker?

Comment: What kind of load 2 space heaters on the same circuit would trip a 15 amp, it all depends on the load, 10 phone chargers probably won't trip the breaker.

Comment: Can you clarify the "15 means 110"?  Are you sure they weren't referring to the voltage?

Comment: I'm sure she meant 15A, 110V (120V).

Answer (score 3):

If you only have one breaker that feeds all of the outlets (plugs are the other end), then there is nothing simple that you can do, someone made that decision when your mobile home was built. In order to change it, an electrician would need to open up the walls and change the wiring, as well as add another breaker in your panel, which may or may not be possible.

Are you absolutely sure all of your outlets are on the same breaker though? A simple way to check is to plug in a radio, turn up the volume, and turn off the breaker. If it goes silent, then that outlet is tied to that breaker. If not, then turn off another breaker to see which one controls it. Do that for every outlet and create a map/list of what rooms are on what breakers. But it might be what you fear. In small mobile homes, they may have a very small breaker panel, so they have one 2 pole / 240V breaker for the Stove / oven, one 2 pole 240V for an Air Conditioner, one single pole 15 or 20A breaker for the kitchen outlets, and one 15A for the rest of the house outlets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your time and make a careful map of all the breakers and which outlets (receptacles or fixed loads) they power.  I like to label each breaker and all controlled outlets with *names*: Liza, Jane, Lydia, Kirk, Spock, Thor, Loki, Odin, Sif, etc.

Note also the number on the breaker, 15 or 20.  That is the allowed **amp**erage of the circuit.

- A 15A circuit can support 1800 watts (1440 continuous).
- A 20A circuit can support 2400 watts (1920 continuous).

Now you can either read the labels on your equipment, or get a $20 "Kill-a-Watt" measuring device and read off the watts of each piece of equipment.  Arrange your appliances so all the appliances added together on the same circuit are within its limits.   If you are within limits and still getting trips, either you mis-mapped the circuits, or you exceeded the limits for *continuous* loads.  I.E. running 1750 watts for several hours on a 15A circuit may trip it.

If all else fails, add more circuits -- nice thing about being in a trailer is you can get underneath it easily enough.